# dynamic floating user controls wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, window

I would like to create a user control which can be dynamically moved when the application is running, using drag and drop (similar to the different view-windows on Visual Studio's interface).

Can such thing be achieved or the controls get "locked" once the application is run?

Comment: FYI, coding ui is EXTREMELY COMPLEX.  You may find yourself way over your head in a very short amount of time.

Comment: Yes it's possible and relatively easy to do if you know what you're doing. For example, if you place a control in a canvas, you can easily change it's `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` property to change the position of the control within the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the WPF [`Thumb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb(v=vs.110).aspx) control. Here's an answer that you should be able to adapt to your purposes: [Drag and drop an image in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3080692/424129)

When a user clicks on a `Thumb` and drags it, it repeatedly fires its `DragDelta` event. He gives the dragged control a `TranslateTransform` named `translateTransform`, and in the `DragDelta` handler he just tacks on the change values to the transform's `X` and `Y`:

```
private void MyRootDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e) 
{
    translateTransform.X += e.HorizontalChange;
    translateTransform.Y += e.VerticalChange;
}
```

If you want to limit the range of motion to the bounds of some parent, you'd use `Math.Min()` and `Math.Max()` and look at the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the parent and the child (unless there's some clever way to do that in pure XAML, but I don't know one). You could probably do `Canvas.SetLeft(ctl)` and `Canvas.SetRight(ctl)` instead.